# Flash/ActionScript - Turning Off Accessibility

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, accessibility

i've designed a UI in Flash IDE, have exported a lot of the objects for ActionScript, and program the application with an external document class .as file.

in Flash IDE, i don't want any of my sliders or textFields to have accessibility options.  i open the Accessibility panel (Window > Other Panels > Accessibility), and with the stage selected i uncheck "Make Movie Accessible".  save.  compile.  runtime error:

```
~/myCustomClass.as, Line 4 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method AccessibilityProperties.
```

line 4 is a simple import:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
```

how can i solve this?

UPDATE:

adding the following imports to my .as removes the runtime error:

```
import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties;
import flash.accessibility.Accessibility;
```

however, the application still allows tabbing.  how can i completely turn off accessibility?

i've tried:

```
Sprite.prototype.tabEnabled = false;
```

but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage won't work , but you should be able to do it with root. 
In the Flash IDE , on the main timeline, add this:

```
var main:MovieClip = this.root as MovieClip();
main.tabEnabled = false;
main.tabChildren = false;
```

Comment: thanks, this worked.  i just had to add this.tabChildren = false; to my main document class.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
stage.tabEnabled = false;
stage.tabChildren = false;
```

Because every display object is a child of the stage, it should stop it globally.

UPDATE:

Because you can't set the tabEnabled property on the stage, you can loop over all the children on it and apply it to them.

```
for(var:int; i < stage.numChildren; i++) {
    var c:DisplayObject = stage.getChildAt(i);

    if(c is InteractiveObject) {
        InteractiveObject(c).tabEnabled = false;
    }

    if(c is DisplayObjectContainer) {
        DisplayObjectContainer(c).tabChildren = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work.  i received a runtime error for trying to set the stage with the tabEnabled property.  it accepted tabChildren but it still allows me to tab.

Comment: Can you post the error? I just did a quick test and it work as I expected, no errors.

Comment: Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method. at Error$/throwError() at flash.display::Stage/set tabEnabled().  it also states in the documentation that an IllegalOperationError will be thrown if tabEnabled is set on the stage:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html

Comment: hmm strange, okay I'll update my answer with alternate solution.